# SSRS table split based on Value keeping headers Constant

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I want to break the table as soon the data encounters June. I want only one table which should split the table keeping the table header intact.  I searched the whole internet but I am not getting any reliable solution I can go with. 
Right now I am getting all the month in a single column, as you can see from the image left side is what I want and right side is what I am getting

[image]

I am trying to achieve this in SSRS 2012

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you want is the same table to appear displaying information for a time period from July to the following June for each year (so July2015-Jun2016, July2016-June2017…)

If you were to use a dataset in the following format (which *looks* similar to that posted in your image above

```
CashFlowYear  theDate     Revenue  Expense
2015          12/01/2015  1000     500 
2016          01/01/2016  1100     1500
```

(Note that the date column where you list a bunch of month names are represented by an actual date here)

You want to create a repeating table, so create a rectangle in your report. Then create your tablix within this rectangle.  It should look something like this.

[image]

Then to get the grouping behaviour that you desire, right-click the List row header, then Row Group -> Group properties and Group it on

```
=year(dateAdd("M", -6, Fields!theDate.Value))
```

This will remove 6 months from each of the dates, and group when they are in the same year (so June 2016 will become December 2015, and be grouped with the other 2015 dates)

When run the report will look like this.

[image]

You can then edit the list to insert a page break between each of the tables if you wish, or whatever additional formatting you require.

Hopefully this will assist you.  Let me know if I can be of further help.

Comment: Yes jonnus I am modifying the Query So that It Displays the year I Wanted , but when I made rectangle and when I tried to enter tablix into the list in rectangle or just tablix into list it throws an error saying it has a detail member with inner members and Detail members can only contain static inner members

Comment: Can you update your original question with an image of your new report layout.  Include the grey row headers is possible

Comment: instead of using List I used Header as List keeping once cell in Tablix as List and Followed the steps you gave and it worked. Thank you so much Jonnus.

Comment: @URVIL SHAH If you found this helpful please mark as answer (the green tick next to the answer) for people who may reference this question in the future